# MS JS Runtime Error....Include AJAX libraries in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.0

Here is image of the error and the code segment where it is erroring out.
[image]

Project was originally developed in VS2010 but was "upgraded" to VS2012 cause client has that dev environment.  Not sure if there are other things i need to do after the upgrade that would resolve this problem or not.

This error only occurs when i place the `Me.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True` in Page_Load, Page Directive, or Web.Config.  I have tried using self reference and `Page` reference and same problem.

If i remove the line of code `Me.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True` from any of the 3 locations the `WebDev.WebServer####` runs the application fine.

Ultimate goals is that i have an undefined length object being loaded into a table.  It could be as little as 5 items in the table or up to 100.  In either case each item has a RadioButtonList object associated with it.  Each RBL when clicked then submits the choice selected back to the SQL server and ultimately refreshes the page.  This setting was suppose to fix the problem of the refresh, or PostBack, from resetting the scroll back to the top.

Found out after removing the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` property but adding in AJAX controls, i received similar errors.

#### Question:

1. <s>Any suggestion on fixing this problem, so it wont occur in VS2010 or VS2012?</s>
2. <s>Is there an alternate approach so i can sustain the scroll position on the page while still submitting the RBL selected index change event to the SQL server?</s>
3. How do i fix this so the JavaScript is either installed on my computer or WebServer instance from VS2010/2012 will use Javascript?
4. Seems this is related to Ajax registration within the `web.config` even though i have it registered in the project.  Anyone know what declaration i need in web.config so ajax is run from the server and doesnt require client interaction?  (FYI, .Net 4)

Comment: Found my problem, VS2010 project initially and then upgraded to VS2012 which evidently didnt like some library references and so botched them.  Recreated the project from scratch from within VS2012, with some minor copy/paste and the problem disappeared.  Memo to me, never port 2010 to 2012, as usual MS botched a intra-application upgrade.

Comment: Also, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631823/659246 for help if you utilize `PageRouting`.

Comment: If any Admin see this post, please Close it.