# Update Panel freezes on Postback

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Have a AJAX UpdatePanel in a MasterPage file:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlTimer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrCountdown"   EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="tmrCountdown" Enabled="false" runat="server" Interval="1000" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" Text="TEXT"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When i goto debug everything works well, dont get the postback flash as the timer counts down.

But when the user makes a selection from a RadioButtonList, of course the SelectedIndexChange events fires off and the PostBack goes off as expected.

One problem i am having though is that the UpdatePanel with the Timer/Label is freezing, albeit fractions of a second, but over time it can increase the time-alloted for the test by up to a full minute (60 secs) pending on the number of questions being asked.

#### Question:

1. <s>Is there a way to isolate the PostBack away from the Timer UpdatePanel from the Question List?</s> Placed an UpdatePanel on the Content Page
2. <s>Would it be better to place the ContentPlaceHolder, in MasterPage, within a UpdatePanel so that its postbacks are isolated from the Timer UpdatePanel?</s>
3. <s>If i isolate the CPH, as #2, I can still access the MasterPage file name as i am right now `CType(me.Master, Main).Event`?</s>
4. Having a problem with the Content Page UpdatePanel, either conflicting or stopping, the MasterPage Timer UpdatePanel.  How would i go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Is there some other client JavaScript code running in the page, related to these objects?

Comment: Sorry found the problem and it was related to PageRouting and resource mapping.  Alot of the problems i was incurring were masking the source of the problem altogether.  Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631823/659246

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the annoying timeout of UpdatePanel. 
I suggest you try to improve any code in the SelectedIndexChanged of your Radiobutton or try another approach without UpdatePanel.