# VS2005 website scriptmanager and updatepanel throw exception while run in VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have website built in Visual Studio 2005 in vb.net. When I run this website on Visual Studio 2015 it throws a run time exception given below. This website works fine in VS2005.

[image]

I don't know what to do...

Comment: If it isn't already make sure this script block is right at the end of the page before the closing `HTML` tag. It's saying the object `Sys` doesn't exist, possibly because the script is firing before everything is ready.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities mentioned in the answers here: [Sys is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322/sys-is-undefined)

Also note the error on line 127 (the closing script tag is incomplete).

Comment: If there are many answers to a question, perhaps it should be flagged as "Too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." Otherwise please provide a specific answer