# Ajax toolkit does not work in chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my asp site, I have a few ajax ModalPopupExtenders, UpdatePanels and a BalloonPopupExtender. The code seem to work perfectly in IE but not in chrome. Any solutions?

I am using the Toolkit version: 4.5.7.1213

Comment: Is there some sort of error message?

Comment: Nope the page simply refreshes. In chrome developer tool there are multiple console errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.`

Comment: Did you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322/sys-is-undefined

Comment: Thanks much for your time! 
When I try to open the page in incognito mode it works perfectly :) Got the tip from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome
Do you have any suggestions for a permanent fix?