# Sys is not defined with ScriptManager and UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When I use the ScriptManager and UpdatePanel (asp.net 4.0)
When I deployed the code to the server, I opened F12 of the browser and found the following error:
"Sys is not defined"

This error is in the js code generated by ScriptManager

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager', 'Form1', ['tUpdatePanel',''], ['btnHistorySearch',''], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>
```

The code of my aspx is as follows：

```
<div class="userContainer">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvHistory" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            RowStyle-Height="20" BorderColor="#e6e6e6" CssClass="gvTable" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field Name" DataField="FieldName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvTopLeft" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Old Value" DataField="OldValue" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvTopLeft" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="New Value" DataField="NewValue" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvTopLeft" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recorded By" DataField="CreatedByName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvTopLeft" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recorded On" DataField="CreatedOn" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvTopLeft" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

**The strange thing is that everything work fine when I debug locally, and so does my colleague, but when deploying to the server, my colleague logs in and sees a normal page, and I see the error described above**

It is worth mentioning that after the comparison, I found that we have different performances about ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd. His request to obtain these two files is normal, and my return is

```
Cannot find the specified user. Please verify your login information.
```

I read the answers from the article below, but it doesn't seem to work for me, can anyone help with this?
[Sys is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322/sys-is-undefined)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use json+html solve the problem.

Comment: And some explain of how you did this might help then???

Comment: I choose to abandon this UpdatePanel and write another html and js code to achieve this function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).